# Elasticsearch returns stored fields as string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I've got a field called `mydate` with the following mapping in ES 5.4:

```
{
  "type": "date",
  "store" : true,
  "format" : "epoch_millis"
}
```

Now, with the following query:

```
POST foo/bar/_search
{
  "query":{ "match_all": {} },
  "stored_fields": [ "mydate" ]
}
```

ES returns:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {...},
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "foo",
        "_type": "bar",
        "_id": "1162256",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "mydate": [
            "1504540873381"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is why the value of the field is returned as string, not long. When I make the query using `_source` it is indeed a long value.

Comment: Interesting question. I looked at the sources trying to figure this out. It uses something called FieldVisitor, which has methods for intValue() and stringValue() and such but no date field. Can you try to use if it happens also with an integer field. Maybe this is a bug. Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/40bb1663eeddca7371bec09b52de8ad67f2e97a3/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fieldvisitor/FieldsVisitor.java

Comment: It does not happen with integer fields. Should I post it as github issue?

Comment: I think so. I'm not a contributor though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but at least it explain why it happens: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26504